# Leaflet - Fitbounds and keep center

Tags: leaflet, fitbounds

I'm using Leaflet with Mapbox and I'd like to set the view of the map so :

1. all markers are visible
2. the center is set to a specific point

It's easy to do each points separately with setView and fitbounds but I don't know how to have both at the same time since setView changes the bounds and fitBounds changes the center. A solution could be to define a center and a zoom but how can I know which zoom will allow all my markers to be visible ?

EDIT

I implemented the solution suggested by IvanSanchez and it works as expected:

```
let ne=leafletBounds.getNorthEast();
let sw=leafletBounds.getSouthWest();
let neSymetric=[ne.lat + (center.lat - ne.lat)*2, ne.lng + (center.lng - ne.lng)*2];
let swSymetric=[sw.lat +(center.lat - sw.lat)*2, sw.lng + (center.lng - sw.lng)*2];
leafletBounds.extend(L.latLngBounds(swSymetric, neSymetric));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get your bounds, and create a second `L.Bounds` instance by applying point symmetry along the centerpoint you want. Create a new `L.Bounds` containing the original bounds and the symmetric bounds. Run `fitBounds()` with that.

Comment: Thank you, that's an easy and efficient solution!

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution to this. You can simply call map.panTo([lat, lng]) after you've adjusted your map with fitBound(). I am using VueJs and calling this in the mounted() lifecycle hook.

I am fitting bounds so you can see a user's location and also a geographic feature far away, but then I use panTo so the user's real location is at the center of the map after fitBounds. It seems to work seamlessly so far.